# Programmatically selecting a Shield UI Pie Chart slice (via Wicket)

Tags: javascript, charts, wicket, wicket-6, shieldui

Is there a way to programmatically select a slice of a Shield UI pie chart via Wicket (or the Javascript API)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to handle this may be to select the item as demonstrated here:
http://www.shieldui.com/documentation/javascript.chart/api/dataSeries/data/selected

Comment: Following on - you can set this via Wicket using dataSeriesItemHashMap.put("selected", true) when setting up your DataSeriesItem hashmaps in ChartOptions.